# How to extract substring from a griven string in java

Tags: java

How to I extract the following substring from a string in Java.

```
string var=fill x [0,4,4,4] #1000ff
```

I want to extract only the `fill x` (with whitespaces).

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you help us helping you by posting what have you tried?

Comment: And by telling us what's the general extraction criterion? You want to extract everything that occurs before '['?

Comment: `string var` feels like JavaScript instead.

Comment: Your example is **not** valid Java syntax.

Comment: You may want to double-check whether you're using Java here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String result = var.substring(0,var.indexOf("["));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String subString = var.substring(begin, end + 1);  
// begin and end is the integer index of var string where you want to get
```

in your example, it should be:

```
String subString = var.substring(0, var.indexOf("["));  // if include white space
String subString = var.substring(0, var.indexOf("x") + 1);  // if not include white space
```